# Amazon S3 policy to allow r/w access to a single bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I have a problem writing AWS policy to grant user read/write access to a single bucket. Basing on examples I found online, it seems to be quite straightforward:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the policy editor returns error *The provided policy document does not meet the requirements of the specified policy type.*

A comment in the policy editor also says:

> To allow actions, include statements with the format '"Effect": "Allow"'. All other actions are implicitly denied.
>   To explicitly deny actions, include statements with the format "Effect": "Deny". **Only Deny statements can include resources and conditions.**

This comment goes against every single example I found. I can't imagine how I could effectively write policies where "allow" effect is used globally without specifying resource, then "deny" is granular and points out the resources it affects.

Comment: Your policy is correct, can you confirm that your are adding this as an inline policy for the user in the IAM console?

Comment: @jogold nope, I've been doing that in "my organization" level :) Thanks for directing me into right track!

Comment: @MichałSałaban what is the principal role that wants to use this policy. better add it directly